# How to publish windows authenticated database on azure cloud?

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have created database driven code-first .net application using identity. The credentials I have used in database is Windows Authentication. In local machine, my registration and login pages are working.

Are there any way where I can publish database and my .net application on cloud? As per my knowledge, I can't use Windows authentication but I have already created it so Is there any method which I can use to publish it on cloud?

Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it using **[Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/)**, or maybe even a **[hybrid solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity)**, but it won't be as easy as using **SQL Server Authentication**. I suggest you just update your connection string (assuming that's your only place you're using AD authentication) to SQL Server Authentication.

Take a look at [Quickstart: Use .NET and C# in Visual Studio to connect to and query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio?view=azure-java-legacy) for a straight forward explanation on how this can be done.

Hope it helps!